# Is there a way I can hide my asked questions from the my profile?

Tags: support, asking-questions, discussion

I usually ask questions related to my studies and I don't like people finding questions via my profile,I don't have a problem at all if they find it via tags.Is there a way I can hide my questions from my profile?

Comment: why has this question been downvoted? It wouldn't be useful for me but I think it's a valid request to be able to suppress any information you don't want others to see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is currently not possible. However, you can always log out of your account and ask your question anonymously—registration is not required to ask questions.

Comment: At present, [some sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/227114/259867) do require registration to ask questions.

Answer (score 7):

I would go so far as to say that I would see this as a mis-feature. I *use* the ability to look up another users past posts in several ways

- Some times a really "bad" post could arise from either a user who isn't strong in English or from simple laziness. The user's history can be very helpful in determining which is most likely, and I can pitch my response accordingly
- If I have some desire to reward another user (for a very good comment, or because their answer to my questions was just *so* great that a vote and an acceptance weren't enough, or whatever) I go to their profile and search for some other *worthy* content of theirs.
- Some users show a pattern of asking vague, ill-founded, and underspecified questions with no obvious purpose. I don't want to spend my time answer them, and looking in their profile is how I tell.

Comment: +1 for mentioning its positive features