# What is the best way to post anonymously?

Tags: discussion, support

I have a thing that is bothering me deeply that I want to ask about without my name on the post. It is rather personal and concerns people I care for.

What would be the best way to make a post like this? Not wanting to have my real account deleted because of one post from a smurf account

Comment: There's no rule that forbids using a second account **as long as there are no interactions (voting, bounties, etc.) between both accounts**. For more information, see: [How should sockpuppets be handled on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57682/348196)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're allowed to post a question without being signed-in (but if you do then you might find it difficult to e.g. edit that question later).

You're also allowed to create a smurf account which you use to post more-anonymous questions.

Only be sure to have no interactions between your several accounts, e.g. don't post with one account and upvote with another.

---

**Edit to add: perhaps this isn't true anymore** -- comments below suggest that now to post you may need to use a registered account, perhaps on all sites (or perhaps on some sites).

Comment: _"You're allowed to post a question without being signed-in"_ Note that [not all sites support this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/227114/348196). Most of them do though.

Comment: I'd favour the alternate account option simply because it lets you respond more effectively to comments and answers. Just remember the general rules linked in the first comment to the question

Comment: Also, by "*without being signed-in*", it means an anonymous cookie-based account is created. As long as they don't clear or overwrite the cookie, then they will always have access to the account and its posts. But if it's cleared, then they will lose access to the account forever, unless requesting an account merging (but that defeats the purpose of this question).

Comment: Am I missing something or is this just out of date? When I try to post a question without being logged into an account I get "You must be logged in to ask a question on Meta Stack Exchange". So it seems that most of this answer doesn't apply anymore.

Comment: @Kvothe Perhaps the rule is different for posting to Meta. I don't know about posting to meta.stackexchange, but posting to a site-specific Meta is a privilege which requires a reputation of 5 and therefore an identity.

Comment: So that means this answer is invalid right? "You're allowed to post a question without being signed-in " Is false, right? It should be edited to reflect this rule right? (And yes I just tried for meta you need an account.)

Comment: @Kvothe The answer is true re. posting on sites (e.g. stackoverflow.com etc.), which is what I assumed the question was asking about. Maybe less true, re. posting on this meta-site.

Comment: @ChrisW, no. The contradiction is in: "posting to a site-specific Meta is a privilege which requires a reputation of 5 and therefore an identity" and "You're allowed to post a question without being signed-in". Both quotes from you. I believe the first is correct. And therefore the second is incorrect. Do you agree? (There does not seem to be any difference between meta and other sites by the way. But this is not at all the issue and seems to have confused you.)

Comment: @Kvothe Posting to a site-specific Meta is a privilege which requires an identity. But you can post to a non-Meta site without being logged in.

Comment: Ah sorry I did misunderstand what you are saying exactly. However, I don't think it is true (or rather it is true but not just for meta but for all stack exchange sites). I just tried 5 stackexchange sites (not their meta) and all require you to log in to ask a question. It looks like (at least by sampling) all stack exchange sites meta or not require you to log in to ask a question.

Comment: The answer here https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/25141/408562 should make it clear that this answer is out of date. (Ah sorry this is only about maths, but that seems to be the case for at least all sites I tried.)

Comment: @Kvothe Perhaps you're right. I see that all the recent questions posted to Buddhism.SE by new users are "registered" users. And one or more regular users who always used unregistered accounts (perhaps for religious reasons) no longer post all.

Comment: One can have unregistered account (i.e. asking without a "real" account) on most sites, but not all. Full list of sites that require logging in can be found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227111/why-are-unregistered-users-not-allowed-to-post-questions-on-some-sites/227114#227114).

Comment: @ShadowTheGPTWizard, thanks for the useful link. Definitely not a full list though. Travel is for example one of the few I tried which also requires an account and isn't on the list. (I was skeptical anything that doesn't require registration even still exists but I found one: cooking!)